# Setting phone numbers in amp-call-tracking based on URL parameter

Tags: json, amp-html

I have an AMP layout where I have included:

`<script async custom-element="amp-call-tracking" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-call-tracking-0.1.js"></script>`

I have seen that I need to include a JSON file, with a list of phone numbers, but the phone number needs to change based on a parameter from within the URL, such as :

https://example.com?bid=1234

The JSON should then look something like:

```
{
    "bid": "1234",
    "phoneNumber": "15559876543",
    "formattedPhoneNumber": "1 (555) 987-6543"
}
```

I can write the JSON, but the phone number isn't updating. I have over 50 bid ID with different phone numbers.

Will this also stay showing the same phone number throughout the users session when on the site?

Comment: hi, did you found a solution to your question? same as mine.